# Spring Data Couchbase: method findBy object throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException "Unsupported type for JsonArray"

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase, illegalargumentexception, spring-data-couchbase

I created a spring boot project. Specified data model:

```
@Document
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field
    private String firstname;

    @Field
    private List<Child> children;

    public User(String id, String firstname, List<Child> children) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.children = children;
    }

    static class Child {
        private String name;
        private int age;

        Child(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

    }

}
```

Also, created Reactive Repository:

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "UserView")
public interface UserViewRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseSortingRepository< UserView, String> {
 List<User> findByChildren(Child child);
 List<User> findByFirstname(String firstname);
}
```

Calling the method **findByChild** has generated an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type for JsonArray: class ru.andyhunt.user.User.Child
    at com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonArray.add(JsonArray.java:214) ~[java-client-2.7.11.jar:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/users" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonArray.add(JsonArray.java:214) ~[java-client-2.7.11.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.support.N1qlQueryCreatorUtils.createExpression(N1qlQueryCreatorUtils.java:94) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.support.N1qlQueryCreatorUtils.prepareExpression(N1qlQueryCreatorUtils.java:66) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.N1qlQueryCreator.create(N1qlQueryCreator.java:109) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.N1qlQueryCreator.create(N1qlQueryCreator.java:88) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.ReactivePartTreeN1qlBasedQuery.getStatement(ReactivePartTreeN1qlBasedQuery.java:72) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.ReactiveAbstractN1qlBasedQuery.execute(ReactiveAbstractN1qlBasedQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:618) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Versions: Spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE
spring-data-couchbase-3.2.3.RELEASE

Why does Spring-Data extension not convert a *User* object to a *JsonObject*?
But, method **getByFirstname** works correctly.

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple JsonArray classes, look at the one you're importing to make sure it's the couchbase jsonarray

Comment: I don't use or import JsonArray.class anywhere. Problem here: org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.query.support.N1qlQueryCreatorUtils#createExpression.

Comment: Oh, it could be a couple of things, it's either, because you named it getByChild(), instead of getByChildren() or possibly because your Child class is static, wihch it needn't be.

Just as a best practice, I would move that out into it's own class or just move it outside of your class, because that kind of class shouldn't be static

Comment: thank you! Sorry, this is my copy/paste error. The problem still exists.

Comment: Did you make your Child class public?

Comment: yes, I do it. My real code more correctly. I take this example from reference doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#basics

Comment: I was looking at this a little more and I realized in the spring docs, they don't have an example of search by child, I don't know if you can search by Child object, maybe you have to use, "findByChildrenName"? Or Age? I'm not sure, just a guess

Comment: Yes, "findByChildrenName" work correctly. But, I want to find records by custom java object. This is stated in the documentation. Example from documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/reference/html: "
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<Person, Long> {

  List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);"

Comment: Maybe try findAllByChildren, if you're expecting a list or just one User findByChildren?

Comment: I've tried findAllByChildren, also. There isn't problem if you use a string instead of an object